# Datalab cannot see symlink in tree view

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I started a Datalab server on GCE using the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce) guide. 
Then I created an additional disk, mounted it with [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) and created a symlink in `/root/datalab` which points to a folder on that disk. However, I cannot access its contents.

(edited after more exploration)

Datalab is running inside of a Docker container, which probably maps `/root/datalab` to `/content/datalab`, so obviously a symlink doesn't actually display the contents of the folder on the host machine, because it points to a non-existing folder inside of the container filespace.

The question then rather becomes how to mount the additional diskspace to the datalab container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #3 from that quickstart has you download a YAML file that defines how the containers run inside of that VM.

You want to modify that file (before creating your VM) to specify the additional mounts. That file is a YAML-formatted Kubernetes [pod config](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_pod).

Two things need to be added to it:

1. A new entry in the "volumes" array [defining the Docker volume on the host](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_volume)
2. A new entry in the "volumeMounts" array for the "datalab-kernel-gateway" container [defining the mount point for that volume in the container](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_volumemount).

For an example of what this will look like, look at the "varlog" volume in that file, and see how it is specified to be mounted by the "logger" container.